# jquery mobile - page doesn't refresh

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have 3 pages:

By clicking the "filter" button on page1, it takes you to page2. Clicking the "grey buttons" on page2 takes you to page3. Clicking the "red buttons" on page2 take you back to page1.

But during all these transitions, the pages lose their styles.

I tried adding this code on page1, but it didn't seem to work very well:

```
$(document).bind('pagechange', function() {
          $('.ui-page-active .ui-listview').listview('refresh');
          $('.ui-page-active :jqmData(role=content)').trigger('create');
        });
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, how you you expect anyone to know?

Comment: @Priya i have seen your page which style are you really saying ? and you are not appending any dynamic content through jqm so .listview('refresh') and .trigger('create'); is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that When the user clicks a link in a jQuery Mobile-driven site, the default behavior of the navigation system is to use that link's href to formulate an Ajax request (instead of allowing the browser's default link behavior of requesting that href with full page load).

This means that any scripts and styles referenced the head of a page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax, but they will execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP.

So I tried to consolidate the styles, as well referenced the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page. This fixed the issue.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Comment: upvote for explaining how you solved your own problem. There are a lot of questions floating around S.O. that are self-answered, but lack clear explanation. Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

If you r using windows 8 navigation, when you navigate to one page to another, the new page css is loaded, if any css selector have the same name, the new css will be valid. When you back you can lose this styles.

Try to use css namespaces for each page and subpage:
https://www.google.com.br/search?q=css+namespace

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure what logic you have are using to navigate to page2 or page3

you can try changePage function  to navigate to different page..

```
    $.mobile.changePage("page2.html", { allowSamePageTransition: true, 
transition: "slide", reloadPage: true });
```

Comment: still pages not getting the styles.

Comment: Hello priya .. please let me know where (on which page) you have added css (stylesheet) file or style tag. or can u please share demo link something...??

Comment: You can see the demo pages in my question section where it reads >>I have 3 pages: Page 1, Page 2, Page 3.    Page 1, 2, 3 are links.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pageChange an Ajax request will be made to that url and it will be loaded only the content inside the div with data-role="page". So everything you have out of this element will be ignored (JS and CSS).